# How to bind jquery function to a dynamic DOM

Tags: jquery, dynamic-binding, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery file upload function on my page like following:

```
$('.new-variant-image')
 .fileupload({ 
       dataType: 'script',
       add: function(e, data){ 
       }
});
```

but the DOM class "new-variant-image" is dynamically created after the page is loaded, so it wouldn't work. I searched ways to bind dynamic event using "on" and "live" but wouldn't get it to work in this case.

Any assistance will be much thanked.

**Edit**

The DOM element "new-variant-image" is created afterwards using AJAX, it works if I put the code after the element is created. BUT I want to avoid that, because when I call the function using ajax multiple times it cause the browser to hang about 2 to 3 seconds.

Comment: When calling a method on an jQuery selector the selector must return an element. As you correctly noted that doesn't work if the element is dynamically added. Using `on` with delegation won't be doing you any good here as you are not looking to bind to an event but rather looking to execute a method against an element. You will have to call `.fileupload` once you have loaded the element. If you are calling the ajax call multiple times you will also have to re-execute the `.fileupload` as each time you re-add the element the plug-in association to the element is destroyed.

Comment: Hi,François Wahl thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @user1883793: You might need to look at slightly re-designing the logic around the AJAX call to load the sets of elements differently, preventing re-loading some of the element or if possible, maybe you could call a method after **all** the AJAX calls are done and do the file upload association with the element within that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function's callback

```
$('.new-variant-image').fileupload({
      dataType: 'script',
     add: function(e, data),
     done: $('.new-variant-image').click(function(){
     })
{
```

Comment: Would this work if I put it before the DOM (.new-variant-image)creations? Thanks

Comment: i dont know what you mean but basically it will work only if the done: function is executed after the DOM element .new-variant-image exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `$('.new-variant-image').fileupload({ dataType: 'script', add: function(e, data){` should be after the element creation code ....

I don't know how you are creating the element(using ajax or something else)...

What georgi-it has suggested should work...

Comment: Hi, The DOM element "new-variant-image" is created afterwards using AJAX, it works if I put the code after the element is created. BUT I want to avoid that, because when I called the function using ajax multiple times it cause the browser to hang about 2 to 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Although very late to answer this question, but as of **jQuery 1.7** you can use [jQuery.fn.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(document).on("click", ".new-variant-image", function () {
    $('.new-variant-image')
            .fileupload({
                dataType: 'script',
                add: function (e, data) {
                }
            });
})
```

This attaches event handler function for all present elements or **dynamically appended** element with class `new-variant-image`.