# fileupload Jquery doesn't work dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-file-upload, dynamically-generated

I use this file-upload script: http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/

There is this in it:

```
$('#upload').fileupload({
```

My Problem is, that i load the content dynamically, so I think I need something like this (because I know this problem from the .click() function):

```
$(document).on('fileupload', '#upload', function () {
```

But this doesn't work. Can anyone help me, how to get this function called when the content with the form with id="upload" is loaded dynamically?

Would be great!

Comment: call $('#upload').fileupload(... after your content has been dynamically loaded?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860839/how-to-bind-jquery-function-to-a-dynamic-dom

Comment: @BGR: I don't understand this, why using callback function, if the function itself doesn't work?

Comment: *"when the content with the form with id="upload" is loaded dynamically?"* - How are you loading the content..?

Comment: @TJ: i load it with ajax after a button is clicked

Comment: can you may create a jsfiddle where you have this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably because you're initializing `$('#upload').fileupload()` in `document.ready()`.

You should initialize the element as file upload (execute `$('#upload').fileupload()`) after you dynamically load the content.

Since you're loading the content via ajax on button click (*according to comments*), you code should be along the following:

```
$(":button").click(function(){
 $.ajax("url",{
   success: function (data){
     //code for injecting the element into DOM
     $('#upload').fileupload(); // initialize it as file upload
   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right about the "I need something like this" part - the issue with your attempt at

```
$(document).on('fileupload', '#upload', function () {
```

is that 'fileupload' is [not an event which is what .on() is expecting](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and that's why it worked for you with the 'click' case and not here.

You should include the `assets/js/script.js` to your page after the `$('#upload')` element is dynamically loaded so that all the content the script needs exists before it is executed. For that take a look at [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) or [a simple dom approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js#answer-14521482) and use it after the code which gets your elements added to the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
 $(function () {
        var options = {
            beforeSubmit: function (formData, jqForm, options) { },  // pre-submit callback 
            success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, form) { }   // post-submit callback 
        };
        // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
        $('#uploadForm').ajaxForm(options);
    });
```